# Couldn't compile java in vs code

Tags: java, terminal, compilation, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

I am not able to run java in vs code [my code]

```
public class hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Hello World")
    }
}
```

. I don't even have an option of run code in terminal in my settings..It is not showing any error or anything too![erased the semi-colon; but not showing any error].JDK-19 is installed and working.

I watched vids on youtube for a solution everyone is saying check "run code in terminal" option. I also downloaded an extention named code runner by which finally  "run code in terminal" option was there I checked it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different IDE to run your Java Code because VS Code doesn't support many features, try: intellij, eclipse,...

Otherwise, please follow the instruction in: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Check current JDK in your computer by typing following command in cmd:

```
java --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Intellij is also good or try to install plugin for java then you will able to run java on vs code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).